# Fastest method to find the dir (path) of the first script (php file) executed

Tags: php, path

There is a faster method than the example below, to find the path/folder of the first script (php file) executed?

```
function script_get_home_path() {    
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();    
    $first_php = $backtrace[count($backtrace)-1]['file'];
    return dirname($first_php);
}
```

The idea is to find the entry point (absolute path) for the current thread of execution, but using the most optimized solution!

I also tried with get_included_files() but it uses more resources, especially in wordpress where there are 200 files included in the returned array.

```
function script_get_home_path() {    
    $included = get_included_files();        
    return dirname(reset($included));
}
```

A solution would be to use

```
function script_get_home_path() { 
   return dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]); 
}
```

but how reliable is it in case the working directory is changed, is the real path still correct?

*The $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] is not a solution, it doesn't give me the necessary path*

**Update:**
In the end, I will try a "universal" version and time will tell us which is the most optimal.

```
function script_get_home_path($method=0) {    
    switch ($method) {
        case 1: return dirname(get_included_files()[0]);            
        case 2: $dbt = debug_backtrace(); return dirname($dbt[count($dbt)-1]['file']);            
        default: return dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);
    }            
}
```

where `$method` can be

- 1 - for `get_included_files`
- 2 - for `debug_backtrace`
- 0 - or any other value for `SCRIPT_FILENAME`

Comment: I would use `get_included_files()[0]`, I wouldn't worry too much about resources when using Wordpress. You'll be using this function once and for a very short time.

Comment: @kiko-software You mean: dirname(get_included_files()[0]) , as long as it is not in a FOR cycle :), I am addicted to performance and optimization from the time when I was programming in ASM (Assembler, 25 years ago)